# Why are all fields a euclidean domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm not sure which euclidean valuation to use for this.

I've seen a proof on the internet and they used the function v(x)=1 for all nonzero elements x in F, field.

But wouldn't this function contradict the condition that v(r) is less than v(b)?

Since both are equal to 1, and v(r) is not zero?

Comment: it does not much matter, the remainder term is always equal to zero

Comment: Why is it always 0?

Comment: You have a field, if you have $a$ and nonzero $b,$ you can always solve $a = q b + r$ with $q = \frac{a}{b}$ and $r=0$